# Single-stage amplifier biased by a simple current mirror device

Tags: amplifier, bjt, differential, current-mirror

the goal is to  the Derive an expression for the voltage gain for the circuit below.
the course notes I have is pretty vague, and I have no idea how they came up with the answer. is there anyone who can explain to how to derive the voltage gain expression. 
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Show what you've got so far (or your course notes) and we can explain where you got stuck or went wrong.

Comment: the course notes just gives the final answer, there is no derivation. and I don't even know where to start !.

Comment: AV= -(ro||r2)/Rs+rπ

Comment: Edit the equation into your question, please. Click the "edit" button in the lower left corner of the post to do so. And add what you think you'd need to do to start. I don't believe that you don't have *any* idea where to start.

Comment: here is what I found out. I know that the gain is the total resistance of collector divided by total resistance of the emitter. but the RC is replaced by two top transistors,

Comment: What is Ro and R2 in relation to the circuit?

Comment: I know ro is the early voltage, but I don't know about r2.

Comment: You should draw the small signal equivalent circuit, that will explain things. Then the answer will be: this circuit has no gain, the gain Vout/Vin is ZERO. Yes really. Not joking, I can explain why but try to figure it out yourself first.

Comment: What the tutor probably wants is your understanding .The idea is that the current mirror has a high output impedence ,so when you ballpark with gmRl you get big gain like in the thousands .Now if you dont want to do what your teacher wants you can say that a battery has zero ohm impedence at colledge so gain is zero because the input is shunted out .Is the tutor trying to set you up or did the person who set the question make a mistake .I remember Colledge it wasnt geared up for people withlearning disabilities like me dont worry not you ,in fact it shouldnt be anyway.

Comment: @Autistic Well spotted, it is indeed the battery Vb1 that shorts the signal to ground, meaning no matter what Vin does, Vout remains zero. This is the kind of excersise that learns you to look at a circuit and think "what happens ?" instead of "blindly" use the formulas you learned. Indeed, it is a trick question to test if you are paying attention :-)

Comment: we built the very same circuit on the breadboard and got the output signal on the oscilloscope  in the Lab, and the gain was NOT zero.